# Is there a connection between the differential gain and the spontaneous emission factor $\beta$ in semiconductor lasers?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, laser, laser-cavity

The section below is from the paper

G. Bjork and Y. Yamamoto, "Analysis of semiconductor microcavity lasers using rate equations," in IEEE Journal of Quantum Electronics, vol. 27, no. 11, pp. 2386-2396, Nov. 1991, doi: 10.1109/3.100877.

It suggestes a connection between the differential gain g' and the spontaneous emission (factor $\beta$) in equation (6). I already did some research but I can't finde any further publications mentioning this relation. The background to my question is that I investigate VCSEL structures with MQW active areas, that should in general result in a higher differential gain and hence offers better dynamic behavoir for short pulse generation than SQW or bulk structures. From measurments of the characteristic curve around the threshold, I obtained the typical S-shaped form from that one can conclude the value or at least the order of magnitude from the spontaneous emission coupling factor $\beta$. It would be intersting for the conclusion of my results, if indeed a higher $\beta$ value would lead to a higher differential gain. However, first I would need derivation for this relation.

[image]

Thank you.